# Access to extra fields in "collection field" of a form that not mapped to object

Tags: symfony

I'm programming a site using `symfony2`.

I have a form that contains a collection of a `From Type` with name `OptionType`. Somthing like this:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
    ->add('short_title', 'text')
    ->add('options', 'collection', array('type' => new OptionType(),'allow_add' => true, 'allow_delete' => true, 'by_reference' => false))
    ...
```

`OptionType` by definition is mapping to an object of `Option` class.

Now I need to add an extra field  to `OptionType` that is not member of `Option` class. for this situation I added this line to `buildForm` funciton of `OptionType`:

```
$builder->add('optionImage', 'file', array('property_path' => false));
```

and it worked, but, problem is how can I access to data of this new field?

In situation that this extra field directly added to form, answer is:

```
$form->get('optionImage')->getData();
```

but here I have a collection of a `From Type` and this code doesn't work.

One of the answer would be "Do not map `OptionType` to `Option` (use form without a class) and get back array of submited data, and handle these data yourself"; but for some reason I don't want to use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$form['options'][0]['optionImage']->getData();
```

where 0 is offset in collection